# DEPRECATED `Bundler.with_clean_env` has been deprecated in favor of `Bundler.with_unbundled_env`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

I just installed ruby on rails using railsinstaller and when I ran "rails new myrubyblog" in the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails, this error occurred. I am not sure what this is and I tried to uninstall ruby on rails and install it again with railsinstaller but that did not seem to help. I've been stuck here for a long time and still cannot figure out a way around. Could anyone give me some hints on this please? Thanks!

```
# Rails Environment Configuration.
C:/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:28:in ``': No such file or directory - C:/RailsInstaller/Git/bin/git.exe config --global user.name (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:28:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:40:in `git_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:48:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:48:in `<main>'

C:\Sites>rails new myrubyblog
       exist
   identical  README.md
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Sites/myrubyblog/.git/
       exist  app
   identical  app/assets/config/manifest.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
   identical  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  app/jobs/application_job.rb
   identical  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
   identical  app/models/application_record.rb
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   identical  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
   identical  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
   identical  app/assets/images/.keep
       exist  app/assets/javascripts/channels
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
   identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
   identical  app/models/concerns/.keep
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
   identical  bin/setup
   identical  bin/update
   identical  bin/yarn
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
    conflict  config/secrets.yml
Overwrite C:/Sites/myrubyblog/config/secrets.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm]
       force  config/secrets.yml
   identical  config/cable.yml
   identical  config/puma.rb
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
   identical  config/initializers/assets.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
       exist  db
   identical  db/seeds.rb
       exist  lib
       exist  lib/tasks
   identical  lib/tasks/.keep
       exist  lib/assets
   identical  lib/assets/.keep
       exist  log
   identical  log/.keep
       exist  public
   identical  public/404.html
   identical  public/422.html
   identical  public/500.html
   identical  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
   identical  public/apple-touch-icon.png
   identical  public/favicon.ico
   identical  public/robots.txt
       exist  test/fixtures
   identical  test/fixtures/.keep
       exist  test/fixtures/files
   identical  test/fixtures/files/.keep
       exist  test/controllers
   identical  test/controllers/.keep
       exist  test/mailers
   identical  test/mailers/.keep
       exist  test/models
   identical  test/models/.keep
       exist  test/helpers
   identical  test/helpers/.keep
       exist  test/integration
   identical  test/integration/.keep
   identical  test/test_helper.rb
       exist  test/system
   identical  test/system/.keep
   identical  test/application_system_test_case.rb
       exist  tmp
   identical  tmp/.keep
       exist  tmp/cache
       exist  tmp/cache/assets
       exist  vendor
   identical  vendor/.keep
   identical  package.json
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb
         run  bundle install
[DEPRECATED] `Bundler.with_clean_env` has been deprecated in favor of `Bundler.with_unbundled_env`. If you instead want the environment before bundler was originally loaded, use `Bundler.with_original_env` (called at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:385)
```

Update:
After deleting ruby and rails I reinstalled ruby 2.6.5. Then I tried to install rails by typing "gem install rails" in the command prompt as instructed by the tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-installation.htm(I also have sqlite3 in my computer). But again I ran into another error like this:

```
C:\>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
D:/ruby\ files/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I D:/ruby\ files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20191228-14032-rudo55.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:269: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:269: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.7.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: (1) which ruby version are you using? (2) are you using rbenv or rvm? (3) which version of rails are you trying to install? (4) are you using bundler?